# How to get rid the indent after the equation

Tags: math-mode, spacing, fontsize

Since my equation in LaTeX is quite large I have decided to increase its size in the following way:

```
%     
\begin{small}     
   \begin{eqnarray}     
       bla bla bla bla              
   \end{eqnarray}              
\end{small}             
%          
text text text
```

Everything looks fine here, except that that the text after the equation starts with an indent, even though I have put `%` between the equation and the text. How can I get rid of the indent?

Comment: As a quick fix, you can put `\noindent` in front of the `text text text`.

Comment: The problem here is that you need `\end{small}%`. However, also see [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln) with the intent of avoiding `eqnarray`. Moreover, it would be advisable to create a macro (or environment) to treat your "change of heart" (making display equations `small`er), since it allows for a more [consistent](http://goo.gl/792Wc) outcome.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: you can set this on your preamble (to affect all text) `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`, that way you won't get any indentation

Answer (score 7):

That's the wrong approach to making an equation smaller. If you notice, the lines above the equation will be irregularly spaced. The small space you see is the end-of-line after `\end{small}`.

Here's an example using your input:

[image]

The bad spacing of lines before the equation is very noticeable and it would be terrible if `\footnotesize` were used.

Also, using `eqnarray` is not recommended; the alignment environments provided by `amsmath` are surely better. I can't recommend using `\begin{small}` and `\end{small}` either. Use `<blank line>{\small ...\par}` when needed (if a paragraph is to be typeset, or `{\small ...}` inside a paragraph in normal size.

There are two possibilities; with the first one the equation number will be normal size; with the second one also the equation numbers will be of reduced size, but it will be easier to accommodate an alignment environment.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}

Some text and some text and some text and some text and some text 
and some text and some text and some text and some text and some 
text and some text and some text and some text and some text and 
some text and some text and some text and some text and some text
\begin{equation}
\mbox{\small$\displaystyle
 a\ very\ very\ long\ equation\ that\ we\ want\ smaller
$}
\end{equation}
some text and some text and some text and some text and some text 
and some text and some text and some text and some text and some 
text and some text and some text and some text and some text and 
some text and some text and some text and some text and some text

\newpage

Some text and some text and some text and some text and some text 
and some text and some text and some text and some text and some 
text and some text and some text and some text and some text and 
some text and some text and some text and some text and some text
\[
\begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}\small
\noindent\begin{equation}
a\ very\ very\ long\ equation\ that\ we\ want\ smaller
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\]
some text and some text and some text and some text and some text 
and some text and some text and some text and some text and some 
text and some text and some text and some text and some text and 
some text and some text and some text and some text and some text

\end{document}
```

I used `twocolumn` just to show the two examples side by side.

[image]